# 3-D looking graphic - What software can be used to create such?

Tags: vector, images

Is there a term for such an image, and what software is used to create a graphic like the following image, for example? It looks like some kind of vector image built from basic shapes.

[image: 3-d looking image]

Comment: Ok, so while I personally wouldnt have much problem drawing that image. It  does underline a issue, ive spent the last 10 years specializing in this kind of things for fun. A better question would be to ask what is the shortest path to acieving this. And unfortunately that answer is use a cad application then color in illustrator or inkscape.

Comment: Affinity Designer (specific vector design app) has an entire suite of iso drawing tools - I used to do these in illustrator, but it was a fair amount of work; in Designer, it’s close to trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is called [isometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) (or simply *isometric*).

There are tons of tutorials online on how to draw such images.

The style is pretty minimal. It could probably be called *Flat Design* or perhaps *Flat Design 2.0* because of the use of gradients.

It can be drawn in any vector drawing application with basic tools. Commonly people would use something like [Adobe Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) (subscription software) or [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (free).